# How can I be a Technical Architect from fresh?

Tags: architecture

I would like to ask if anyone can advise me the path to be a Salesforce Developer.

1. Where should I start?
2. What Certification should I start up?
3. How can I get learning materials and free hands-on training site for those training?

Comment: go to https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en for training and http://certification.salesforce.com/ for the certification path.

Comment: Hi Mixie, please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. First of all, this question is very broad and demonstrates almost no research effort on your part. Second of all, solicitations to reach out via private channels are extremely inappropriate for this site and will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the certification paths at [Salesforce Certification site](http://certification.salesforce.com/) and free online training at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en).

As a Developer the Platform Developer 1 certification is the starting point and opens up the architecture certification paths.